# how to clear this error ? No module named "tweepy"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I tried using the following command to import tweepy in my system into the folder- c/python27/Scripts/tweepy :

git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git

cd tweepy

python setup.py install

But, when i tried to import tweepy and use it in my program, i'm still getting error as:

"No module named tweepy"

My programs are in c:/Users/xxxx/.spyder-py3/, what else should i do to correct this error.

Comment: tough to know without being on your system. What does `echo %PYTHONPATH%` give you

Comment: try pip install tweepy

Comment: You installed tweepy to Python 2.7, and it looks like you're then using python 3 (.spyder-py3). After you make sure you're using the right interpreter, you should consider installing with pip like so `python3 -m pip install tweepy`.